# How to create an installer for a linux application?

Tags: installation

Like windows, can we create an installer for linux software with a user interface ?

I want to crate an installer for linux application. Is it possible to do so in linux ?

Comment: That would be a package on Linux, Debian based distributions (like Ubuntu) use .deb packages with APT (`apt-get install ...`), some distributions use prm packages which are similar. Google will find a lot of usefull information about theses ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use InstallAnywhere or InstallShield Universal to create .bin installer which support number of platforms like Linux, aix, solaris e.t.c. However both are quite antique and probably there should be something newer.